# Using CURSOR to fetch multiple table names from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've created one table "Meta_Data_Table_Names" where I inserted   forty eight  table names   in the MetaTableName column.  And there is another column to provide Row count with corresponding table name.

I wanted to fetch the table name from “Meta_Data_Table_Names” and execute SELECT Query sequentially through Loop for validation purpose.
Whenever, I execute from TOAD , It’s throwing an error:
Table or view does not exist.

Do we need to make a place holder for 'Meta_name' which can be scanned? Or any particular syntax to read the value during Query?

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT MetaTableName FROM Meta_Data_Table_Names;
    CURSOR c2 IS SELECT ROW_COUNT FROM Meta_Data_Table_Names;
    Meta_name  Meta_Data_Table_Names.MetaTableName%TYPE;
    Count_num Meta_Data_Table_Names.ROW_COUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    OPEN c2;
    FOR i IN 1..48 LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO Meta_name;
        FETCH c2 INTO Count_num;
        IF (Count_num > 2000)
           THEN
               SELECT * FROM  Meta_Name  X 
               MINUS  
               SELECT * from   ASFNCWK07.Meta_Name@NCDV.US.ORACLE.COM Y
               UNION ALL
               SELECT * FROM  ASFNCWK07.Meta_Name@NCDV.US.ORACLE.COM  Y 
               MINUS  
               SELECT  * FROM  Meta_Name  X;    
           ELSE    
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No Validation is required');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: In the SELECT statement, what did you intend to have "Meta_Name" mean? In the DECLARE section it's declared as a variable of type Meta_Data_Table_Names.MetaTableName%TYPE, which you can't SELECT from. Is "Meta_Name" also the name of a table? If it is I suspect you'll have to qualify it with a schema name to have it located properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

MetaTableName is the column where all the table names are stored in this table Meta_Data_Table_Names.  Cursor C1 is defined for MetaTableName where Meta_name is a place holder. I've modified the code with the following, but it's showing different error now. I think the syntax is still incorrect in this dynamic query.

Comment: Cursor C2 should be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM META_DATA_TABLE_NAMES`, but I suggest this shouldn't be a cursor - it's only going to return a single row and you're going to try to fetch from it 48 times. I recommend that this cursor be replaced with a direct invocation of `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COUNT_NUM FROM META_DATA_TABLE_NAMES`.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not allow you to do queries with dynamic table names, i.e. if the table name is not known at compile time. Do do that, you need [Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/dynamic.htm#LNPLS513), which is a bit too broad to go into here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

Firstly, we cannot use variable names in normal SQL: for this we need dynamic SQL.  For instance:

```
 execute immediate 'select 1 from '|| Meta_Name || into n;
```

There are a lot of subtleties when working with dynamic SQL: the PL/SQL documentation devotes a whole chapter to it.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011).

Secondly, when executing SQL in PL/SQL, we need need to provide a target variable.  This must match the projection of the executed query.  When selecting a whole row the `%ROWTYPE` keyword is useful.  Again the documentation covers this: [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345).  Which leads to ...

Thirdly, because you're working with dynamic SQL and you don't know in advance which tables will be in scope, you can't easily declare target variables.  This means you'll need to use ref cursors and/or Type 4 dynamic SQL techniques.  Yikes!  Read Adrian Billington's [excellent blog article here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422).

Lastly (I think), the UNION ALL in your query doesn't allow you to identify which rows are missing from where.  Perhaps that doesn't matter.